# how can i check if lat long of my current location is on polyline using flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, latitude-longitude, polyline

I made a Google map using flutter and drew two polyline on the map. I want to check if the current location is on the polyline or not.

- first i need to check if my current location is on the same
- this code is for how i get polyline and list of polyline coordinates
- i have current location LatLng and list of polyline LatLng

polyline

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Directions {
  final LatLngBounds bounds;
  final List<PointLatLng> polylinePoints;
  final String polylinePointsString;

  final String totalDistance;
  final String totalDuration;
  final String alternativeTotalDistance;
  final String alternativeTotalDuration;
  final List<PointLatLng> alternativePolylinePoints;
  final String alternativePolylinePointsString;

  const Directions(
      {@required this.polylinePointsString,
      @required this.alternativePolylinePointsString,
      @required this.alternativePolylinePoints,
      @required this.alternativeTotalDistance,
      @required this.alternativeTotalDuration,
      @required this.bounds,
      @required this.polylinePoints,
      @required this.totalDistance,
      @required this.totalDuration});

  factory Directions.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    //check route is not available
    if ((map['routes'] as List).isEmpty) return null;

    final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(map['routes'][0]);
    final routeList = map['routes'] as List;

    //bounds
    final northeast = data['bounds']['northeast'];
    final southwest = data['bounds']['southwest'];
    final bounds = LatLngBounds(
        southwest: LatLng(southwest['lat'], southwest['lng']),
        northeast: LatLng(northeast['lat'], northeast['lng']));

    //distance & duration
    String distance = '';
    String duration = '';
    if ((data['legs'] as List).isNotEmpty) {
      final leg = data['legs'][0];
      distance = leg['distance']['text'];
      duration = leg['duration']['text'];
    }

    // Map for allternative route
    List<PointLatLng> alternativeRoutePolyLinePoints;
    String alternativePolylinePointsString;
    String alternativeDistance;
    String alternativeDuration;

    // If alternative is available
    if ((map['routes'] as List).length > 1) {
      final alternativeRoute = Map<String, dynamic>.from(map['routes'][1]);
      alternativeRoutePolyLinePoints = PolylinePoints()
          .decodePolyline(alternativeRoute['overview_polyline']['points']);
      alternativePolylinePointsString =
          alternativeRoute['overview_polyline']['points'];
      alternativeDuration = alternativeRoute['legs'][0]['duration']['text'];
      alternativeDistance = alternativeRoute['legs'][0]['distance']['text'];
    } else {
      alternativeRoutePolyLinePoints = null;
      alternativeDuration = null;
      alternativeDuration = null;
    }

    return Directions(
        alternativePolylinePoints: alternativeRoutePolyLinePoints,
        alternativeTotalDistance: alternativeDistance,
        alternativeTotalDuration: alternativeDuration,
        bounds: bounds,
        polylinePointsString: data['overview_polyline']['points'],
        alternativePolylinePointsString: alternativePolylinePointsString,
        polylinePoints: PolylinePoints()
            .decodePolyline(data['overview_polyline']['points']),
        totalDistance: distance,
        totalDuration: duration);
  }

//get route information

}
```

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import '../model/directions_model.dart';

class DirectionsRepository {
  static const String _baseUrl =
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?';
  final Dio _dio;
  DirectionsRepository({Dio dio}) : _dio = dio ?? Dio();
  Future<Directions> getDirections({
    @required bool alternative,
    @required LatLng origin,
    @required LatLng destination,
    @required String mode,
  }) async {
    final response = await _dio.get(_baseUrl, queryParameters: {
      'origin': '${origin.latitude},${origin.longitude}',
      'destination': '${destination.latitude},${destination.longitude}',
      'mode': '$mode',
      // 'waypoints':'${waypoints}',
      'alternatives': alternative ? 'true' : 'false',
      'key': "google api key",
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      log(response.data.toString());
      return Directions.fromMap(response.data);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code on how you implemented polylines. For me when i implemented polyline, i can get polyline coordinates according to index.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KamrulHasanJony i have LatLng of my current location and i get polyline coordinates as list of LatLng